# Checking if the point is on the line segment

Tags: c++, comparative-review, computational-geometry

Previously, I wrote the following code:

```
bool Line2d :: IsOnLine(Point2d & point)
{
    double dx = end.x - start.x;
    double dy = end.y - start.y;
    return (((point.x - start.x) * dy) 
        == ((point.y - start.y) * dx));
}

double  Line2d :: GetSlope()
{
    double dx = end.x - start.x;
    double dy = end.y - start.y;

    double m = dy/dx;

    return m;
}

bool  Line2d :: IsIntersectable(Line2d & ln)
{
    bool isInt;

    if(this->GetSlope() - ln.GetSlope() == 0)
    {
        isInt = false;
    }
    else
    {
        isInt = true;
    }

    return isInt;
}
```

My code is directly based on Coordinate Geometric formula and thereby easy to understand.

Recently, I found this code [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-check-if-a-given-point-lies-inside-a-polygon/) on the net:

This code looks inedible to me.

> ```
> // A C++ program to check if a given point lies inside a given polygon
> // Refer http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/
> // for explanation of functions onSegment(), orientation() and doIntersect()
> #include <iostream>
> using namespace std;
>
> // Define Infinite (Using INT_MAX caused overflow problems)
> #define INF 10000
>
> struct Point
> {
>     int x;
>     int y;
> };
>
> // Given three colinear points p, q, r, the function checks if
> // point q lies on line segment 'pr'
> bool onSegment(Point p, Point q, Point r)
> {
>     if (q.x <= max(p.x, r.x) && q.x >= min(p.x, r.x) &&
>             q.y <= max(p.y, r.y) && q.y >= min(p.y, r.y))
>         return true;
>     return false;
> }
>
> // To find orientation of ordered triplet (p, q, r).
> // The function returns following values
> // 0 --> p, q and r are colinear
> // 1 --> Clockwise
> // 2 --> Counterclockwise
> int orientation(Point p, Point q, Point r)
> {
>     int val = (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) -
>               (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y);
>
>     if (val == 0) return 0;  // colinear
>     return (val > 0)? 1: 2; // clock or counterclock wise
> }
>
> // The function that returns true if line segment 'p1q1'
> // and 'p2q2' intersect.
> bool doIntersect(Point p1, Point q1, Point p2, Point q2)
> {
>     // Find the four orientations needed for general and
>     // special cases
>     int o1 = orientation(p1, q1, p2);
>     int o2 = orientation(p1, q1, q2);
>     int o3 = orientation(p2, q2, p1);
>     int o4 = orientation(p2, q2, q1);
>
>     // General case
>     if (o1 != o2 && o3 != o4)
>         return true;
>
>     // Special Cases
>     // p1, q1 and p2 are colinear and p2 lies on segment p1q1
>     if (o1 == 0 && onSegment(p1, p2, q1)) return true;
>
>     // p1, q1 and p2 are colinear and q2 lies on segment p1q1
>     if (o2 == 0 && onSegment(p1, q2, q1)) return true;
>
>     // p2, q2 and p1 are colinear and p1 lies on segment p2q2
>     if (o3 == 0 && onSegment(p2, p1, q2)) return true;
>
>      // p2, q2 and q1 are colinear and q1 lies on segment p2q2
>     if (o4 == 0 && onSegment(p2, q1, q2)) return true;
>
>     return false; // Doesn't fall in any of the above cases
> }
>
> // Returns true if the point p lies inside the polygon[] with n vertices
> bool isInside(Point polygon[], int n, Point p)
> {
>     // There must be at least 3 vertices in polygon[]
>     if (n < 3)  return false;
>
>     // Create a point for line segment from p to infinite
>     Point extreme = {INF, p.y};
>
>     // Count intersections of the above line with sides of polygon
>     int count = 0, i = 0;
>     do
>     {
>         int next = (i+1)%n;
>
>         // Check if the line segment from 'p' to 'extreme' intersects
>         // with the line segment from 'polygon[i]' to 'polygon[next]'
>         if (doIntersect(polygon[i], polygon[next], p, extreme))
>         {
>             // If the point 'p' is colinear with line segment 'i-next',
>             // then check if it lies on segment. If it lies, return true,
>             // otherwise false
>             if (orientation(polygon[i], p, polygon[next]) == 0)
>                return onSegment(polygon[i], p, polygon[next]);
>
>             count++;
>         }
>         i = next;
>     } while (i != 0);
>
>     // Return true if count is odd, false otherwise
>     return count&1;  // Same as (count%2 == 1)
> }
>
> // Driver program to test above functions
> int main()
> {
>     Point polygon1[] = {{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}};
>     int n = sizeof(polygon1)/sizeof(polygon1[0]);
>     Point p = {20, 20};
>     isInside(polygon1, n, p)? cout << "Yes \n": cout << "No \n";
>
>     p = {5, 5};
>     isInside(polygon1, n, p)? cout << "Yes \n": cout << "No \n";
>
>     Point polygon2[] = {{0, 0}, {5, 5}, {5, 0}};
>     p = {3, 3};
>     n = sizeof(polygon2)/sizeof(polygon2[0]);
>     isInside(polygon2, n, p)? cout << "Yes \n": cout << "No \n";
>
>     p = {5, 1};
>     isInside(polygon2, n, p)? cout << "Yes \n": cout << "No \n";
>
>     p = {8, 1};
>     isInside(polygon2, n, p)? cout << "Yes \n": cout << "No \n";
>
>     Point polygon3[] =  {{0, 0}, {10, 0}, {10, 10}, {0, 10}};
>     p = {-1,10};
>     n = sizeof(polygon3)/sizeof(polygon3[0]);
>     isInside(polygon3, n, p)? cout << "Yes \n": cout << "No \n";
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Can you compare understandability, convenience of use, and, efficiency of both of them?

Should I use my version of code, or, this version of code?

Just now I found a [math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/221530/6704). This answer do not discuss anything about gradient/slope technique. Why?

Comment: The two pieces of code don't do the same thing. What exactly is it that you need compared?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author is not actually seeking a review of his own code.  Instead, we're being asked to compare the author's code to *someone else's code* and tell the author which set of code to use.  The author appears completely uninterested in improving his own code (he'd rather just use the other code if it's better).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of things I see with both versions of code that could be improved.

### Understand the problem

First, let's make sure we understand the problem.  Let's say we have the following points:

```
Point A{0,0}; 
Point B{2,2};
Point C{4,4}; 
Point D{0,2};
Point E{-1,-1};
```

If we define a line segment \$\overline{AC}\$, then points \$A\$, \$B\$, and \$C\$ are on that line segment.  Point \$E\$ is collinear but not on the segment, and point \$D\$ is neither collinear nor on the segment.

### Write test code

Here is a `main` that will exercise the code.

```
int main()
{
    Point A{0,0}; 
    Point B{2,2};
    Point C{4,4}; 
    Point D{0,2};
    Point E{-1,-1};

    Line2d AC{A,C};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    SHOW(AC);
    SHOW(AC.IsOnLine(A));
    SHOW(AC.IsOnLine(B));
    SHOW(AC.IsOnLine(C));
    SHOW(AC.IsOnLine(D));
    SHOW(AC.IsOnLine(E));

    SHOW(AC.online(A));
    SHOW(AC.online(B));
    SHOW(AC.online(C));
    SHOW(AC.online(D));
    SHOW(AC.online(E));

    Line2d AD{A,D};
    SHOW(AD);
#if 0
    // the IsOnLine function fails for vertical line segments
    SHOW(AD.IsOnLine(A));
    SHOW(AD.IsOnLine(B));
    SHOW(AD.IsOnLine(C));
    SHOW(AD.IsOnLine(D));
    SHOW(AD.IsOnLine(E));
#endif

    SHOW(AD.online(A));
    SHOW(AD.online(B));
    SHOW(AD.online(C));
    SHOW(AD.online(D));
    SHOW(AD.online(E));

}
```

The `IsOnLine` function is the one you wrote.  I've created a different member function to test the other code.  That looks like this:

```
bool Line2d::online(const Point& p) const
{
    return orientation(start, p, end) == 0 && onSegment(start, p, end);
}
```

Also, `SHOW` is a macro that I often use for debugging:

```
#define SHOW(X) std::cout << # X " = " << (X) << std::endl;
```

I've also added some printing capabilities to `Point` and `Line2d` to make it simple.

#### Results

```
AC = [(0, 0), (4, 4)]
AC.IsOnLine(A) = true
AC.IsOnLine(B) = true
AC.IsOnLine(C) = true
AC.IsOnLine(D) = true
AC.IsOnLine(E) = true
AC.online(A) = true
AC.online(B) = true
AC.online(C) = true
AC.online(D) = false
AC.online(E) = false
AD = [(0, 0), (0, 2)]
AD.online(A) = true
AD.online(B) = false
AD.online(C) = false
AD.online(D) = true
AD.online(E) = false
```

As we can see, your function seems not to correctly identify when points are actually on a line segment, while the other routine does.  There are other problems, listed below.

### Avoid dividing by zero

If we define a vertical `Line2d`, all attempts to call `IsOnLine()` will result in division by zero.  It's usually best to avoid this by either rearranging the mathematics to avoid division or to somehow intelligently avoid specifically division by zero.  Another possibility is to throw an exception.  Note that the other code does no division, neatly avoiding this problem.

### Use const where practical

Your `IsOnLine` function uses a reference for the passed `Point` which is good, but it should be `const` since the `Point` is not altered.  Further the `Line2d` object is also not altered, so it should be declared `const` as well:

```
bool Line2d::online(const Point& p) const
```

### Use references where practical

The `orientation` and `onSegment` functions could all take `const` references rather than passing by value.

```
int orientation(const Point &p, const Point &q, const Point &r)
```

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.  It isn't necessarily wrong to use, but be aware of when you absolutely shouldn't do it (such as in header files).

### The bottom line

In all, I'd use the `orientation()` and `onSegment()` routines instead.  They are reliable and understandable once you understand how they work.  However, I would also apply the suggestions above before actually using them.

Answer (score 6):

I understand you are asking for a function to check if a point is on a line. The question itself is ill-posed: because the representation of points and lines on a computer is only approximate and if you approximate a point on a line you probably get a point which is no longer on the line.

A typical example is to check if the number `x` satisfies the equation `x*x == 2.0`. Even if we expect to find a solution to this equation (because we use the real numbers as mental representation) there is no floating point number which solves such equation. Hence it is almost always wrong to check for equality of two floating point numbers.

In this cases what you are looking for is an appropriate approximation. So instead of looking for `x*x == 2.0` one is happy enough to solve `fabs(x*x - 2.0) < 0.0000001`. The small value `epsilon = 0.0000001` is somewhat arbitrary, and can depend on the problem you want to solve.

So my suggestion is to implement a function which computes the distance from point to line https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line and use it to check if the distance is small enough.

There are many other factual problems with your code. Here:

```
bool Line2d :: IsOnLine(Point2d & point)
{
    return (((point.x - start.x) / (end.x - start.x)) == ((point.y - start.y) / (end.y - start.y)));
}
```

there is a division by zero when the lines are vertical. You should moltiply both sides of equation by the denumerators to avoid this and to have a more stable condition. Anyway it is almost always wrong to check for equality of two floating point numbers, as already said.

The function `GetSlope` and `IsIntersectable` are not used. Why did you include them?

Anyway note that vertical lines have no slope defined. So the function `GetSlope` is not very useful.

The function `IsIntersectable` also has the problem above (checking for equality of two floating point numbers). And due to the problem of `GetSlope` it will not work if one of the two lines is vertical.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me what you want compared. But here are some thoughts on both pieces of code.

Your code seems pretty straightforward and clear to read and understand. I would make the following changes, including fixing one bug:

### Use const for things that don't change

Each of your methods calculates values without changing any member variables (it appears). They should be declared as `const`. Furthermore, none of the arguments are altered, so they should also be `const`. I'd declare them as follows:

```
class Line2D {
//...
public:
    bool IsOnLine(const Point2d & point) const;
    double  GetSlope() const;
    bool  IsIntersectable(const Line2d & ln) const;
// ...etc.
};
```

### A potential problem

You also have a potential error in your `GetSlope()` method. `dx` can be zero which will lead to it returning a `NaN` when you divide by 0. If that happens, then the comparison in `IsIntersectable()` will fail, even if both lines have no slope. (`NaN - NaN` == `NaN`, not 0, I believe.)

Also, `IsIntersectable()` can be simplified (at least until you try to deal with the `NaN` issue):

```
bool  Line2d :: IsIntersectable(Line2d & ln)
{
    return (this->GetSlope() - ln.GetSlope() == 0);
}
```

### The other code

As for the code you found, it doesn't appear to me to be doing the same thing. It seems to be figuring out if a point lies on a polygon. It further seems to be ordering several points.

For C++ code, it doesn't appear to use most of the useful features of C++. It's basically just C code that uses `std::cout` instead of `printf()`. It makes no use of classes, which would be useful in this case for points and lines. The naming is confusing - apparently a line consists of points `p1` and `q1` and another line is `p2` and `q2`.

The definition of `INF` as `10000` also strikes me as a potential source of bugs in the future, but maybe it's a non-issue for polygons that typically all fit on a screen? It just seems small to use for infinity to me.

Comment: "As for the code you found, it doesn't appear to me to be doing the same thing." ---- I was talking about bool IsOnLine(const Point2d & point);
    double  GetSlope();
    bool  IsIntersectable(const Line2d & ln);  --- not the whole program.  Which version should I use: mine or that?

Comment: @anonymous: What exactly should be compared? In the "other" code I can see no function which checks if a point is on a line or if two *lines* intersect.

Comment: @MartinR,  Really?  `bool onSegment()` and `bool doIntersect()`???

Comment: @MartinR,  understandability, convenience of use, and, efficiency.

Comment: @anonymous: The comment above `onSegment()` says: *"Given three colinear points p, q, r, the function checks if point q lies on line segment 'pr'"*. That means that p, q, r are already *assumed* to be located on a straight line. The function only checks if q is *between* p and r or not. And `doIntersect()` is about  line *segments*, not lines.

Comment: @MartinR, mine is also about line segments not lines. Where do u think start and end come from? And, please do not only read comments. Read codes also.

Comment: @anonymous: Your `IsOnLine()` method checks (if I understand it correctly) if `point` lies on the (infinite) line joining `start` and `end`, so I cannot see anything about segments here. Your `IsIntersectable()` compares the slopes, which means that it checks if the (infinite) lines intersect or not. – *"Read codes also."* I did, perhaps I am to dumb to understand it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26508/discussion-between-anonymous-and-martin-r).

Comment: @MartinR,   How do u differentiate between a line and a line-segment?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_segment: A *line segment* is a part of a *line* that is bounded by two distinct end points, and contains every point on the line between its end points.

Comment: @MartinR, if a line is dilimited by 2 end points, how can it be a line extending both sides to infinity?

Comment: @MartinR, does my line have two end points or not?